# Why can't we apply L'Hôpital's rule when trying to find the asymptote of an oscillating curve?

Tags: calculus

When trying to find the asymptote ( $g(x) = mx + h$ ) of a curve $f(x)$, we can do:

$\lim_{x\to \infty}(f(x)-g(x))=0$

$\lim_{x\to \infty}(f(x)-mx-h)=0$

$\lim_{x\to \infty}(f(x)) - lim_{x\to \infty}(mx) - lim_{x\to \infty}(h)=0$

$\lim_{x\to \infty}(\frac{f(x)}{x}) - lim_{x\to \infty}(\frac{mx}{x}) - lim_{x\to \infty}(\frac{h}{x})=0$

$\star\lim_{x\to \infty}(\frac{f(x)}{x})=m$

This way we find $m$, the slope of the asymptote, and then we can find $h$ with the second equation, findind $g(x)$.

A geometric way to think is, $f'(x)=\frac{d(f(x))}{dx}$ gives us the slope of the tangent line of the curve, and, as x approaches infinity, we want that $f'(x)=m$, so:

$\lim_{x\to \infty}(f'(x))=m$

And this can be verified applying L'Hôpital's rule in the $\star$ equation.

However, it is not always true that $\lim_{x\to \infty}(f'(x))=m$. For example, if we have a kind of function oscillating and getting smaller, there is an asymptote, but the slope of the tangent of this function doesn't seems to approach anything, as the function oscillates.
[image]

This way, in this case, $\lim_{x\to \infty}(\frac{f(x)}{x})=m$ is true, but $\lim_{x\to \infty}(f'(x))=m$ is not true, which looks like we can't apply L'Hôpital's rule (even though when $x$ tends to infinity, $f(x)$ also tends to infinity).

So, my question is, why can't we apply L'Hôpital's rule in this case?

Comment: You have $\infty - \infty$ above and that should make your brain hurt.

Answer (score 1):

L'Hopital says it is basic case

> If $\lim f(x)=\lim g(x)=0$  and $\lim\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ exists, then $\lim\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists and equals $\lim\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$.

It may always happen that  $\lim\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists, but   $\lim\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ does not.